# How can I make the wrapper of my component be a ngBoostrap Popover?

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I have a child component in my angular ngBoostrap project and I want a popOver to open when someone clicks on that component.

The component is created programmatically so it is non-trivial to add attributes to the html-wrapper.

```
let componentRef = this.someVar.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

I tried adding the necessary attributes in the host-property:

```
  host: {
    "placement": "left",
    "popoverTitle":"Links",
    "ngbPopover": "test",
  }
```

or something like this:

```
  @HostBinding('ngbPopover') private test: string = "Test";
  @HostBinding('placement') private placement: string = "left";
  @HostBinding('popoverTitle') private popoverTitle: string = "Test";
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to achieve this without creating another element inside the component?